# How to merge various MySQL queries results in a single JSON object

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, express

I'm trying to write a REST API set in NodeJS to retrieve data from my MySQL database.

Here the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');


var app = express();
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'apitest',
  port     : '3306',
  multipleStatements: true
});


app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();

});

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {

    connection.query('SELECT name, surname, address FROM users', function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (results) {
            res.status(200).send(results);
        };
    });
});

app.get('/users/:userId', function (req, res) {

    var userId = req.params.userId;

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE idUser = ?', [userId], function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result) {
            res.status(200).send(result);
        };
    });

});

app.get('/users/:userId/photos', function (req, res) {

    var userId = req.params.userId;

    connection.query('SELECT date, file, tags FROM photos WHERE idUser = ?', [userId], function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (results) {
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(results));
        }
    });

});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Listening on http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

Everything goes well if I use the single REST call as written above.
The problem is that I want it to work differently, so when i call `/users/:userId` i want to retrieve user data and the relative photos in a single, well structured, JSON response.

Eg:

```
{
    "name" : "John",
    "surname" : "Doe",
    "photos" : [
        {
            "date" : "2015-04-19T22:00:00.000Z",
            "file" : "photo1.jpg",
            "tags" : "holidays, 2015"
        },
        {
            "date" : "2015-04-19T22:00:00.000Z",
            "file" : "photo2.jpg",
            "tags" : "holidays, 2015, nassau"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've find a workaround by modifying the `/users/:userId` call as mentioned above:

```
app.get('/users/:userId', function (req, res) {

    var userId = req.params.userId;

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE idUser = ?', [userId], function(err, results1) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (results1) {

            connection.query('SELECT date, file, tags FROM photos WHERE idUser = ?', [userId], function(err, results2) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (results2) {
                    results1[0].photos = results2;
                    res.status(200).end(JSON.stringify(results1[0]));
                }
            });

        }
    });

});
```

Everything seems to go well but I think is not the right way because if i want to add more information from other tables in my object i would have to nest more and more functions...

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async), or any one of the popular promise libaries([when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when), [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)).

In Async, it might look something like this.

```
var async = require('async');

app.get('/users/:userId', function (req, res) {

  var userId = req.params.userId;
  async.parallel({
    user: function(callback){
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE idUser = ?', [userId], callback)
    },
    photos: function(callback){
      connection.query('SELECT date, file, tags FROM photos WHERE idUser = ?', [userId], callback)
    }
  },
  // Final callback, with all the results
  function(err, results){
    //results now has {user: ..., photos: ...}
    var user = results.user;
    user.photos = results.photos;
    res.status(200).end(JSON.stringify(user));
  });


});
```

Adding another call is as simple as adding another function inside `parallel` (or whatever it may be).  The code is pretty similar for the promise libraries so I'll leave that as an exercise to you!

Let me know that this helped.